# Difference in dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

There are two dates :  01-11-2008 and 28-02-2017 (in dd/mm/yy format). I want excel to calculate the difference between these two dates and give the output in whole years.

If the difference between months is greater than Six(6) months then it should be rounded of to one year or else ignore.

I have inserted the following formula which is giving the result of 9 years whereas it should be 8 years.

```
=ROUNDUP((YEAR(LDate)-YEAR(EDate))+(IF(MONTH(LDate)-MONTH(EDate)>6,1,0))/12,0)
```

As to how 8 years are derived is shown as follows (dd/mm/yy):

```
01-11-2008 to 31-12-2008 -- 2 month
01-01-2009 to 31-12-206  -- 96 Months
01-01-2017 to 28-02-2017 -- 2 months
               total       100 months
```

100/12 = 8.33 i.e 8 years.

Can some body give me a correct formula on this please?

Comment: you know YEAR(LDate)-YEAR(EDate)= 9 already you need to check it

Comment: `=ROUND((LDate-EDate)/365,0)` this formula will do

Comment: @yass Please don't provide answers in the comments. If you would like to help, post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the difference to be based on months, you could simply use this:

```
=ROUND(DATEDIF(EDate,LDate,"m")/12,0)
```

If you want it to be based on days, use the formula yass provided in the comments:

```
=ROUND((LDate-EDate)/365,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DATEDIF formula as follows

I am assuming you have Start Date in cell C1 and End date in D1,the formula goes like this

```
=SUM(DATEDIF(C1,D1,"Y"),IF(DATEDIF(C1,D1,"YM")>6,1,0))
```

But try giving the date in MM/DD/YYYY format,it will fetch the correct answer.